# Logcat Displays Various Types of Errors for The SQLite Database I Created for My Android App

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to build and an Android app and managed to get through the main purpose of it. However, I'm severely stuck in successfully implementing an SQLite database to have users login if they already have an account off the SQLite database OR create and register for an account.

The relevant classes and XML files for these instructions are correct in my perspective but I believe there's something wrong with my SQLite Query or something wrong when I'd try to look into the Logcat and check for the the registered information from the app user and would display numerous of errors that I find too difficult to debug at this rate.

I will attach the relevant classes, XML files, and what it says at Logcat. Hopefully this way, I can receive the help I'd need as this is severely stopping me from even entering to the main purpose of the app. Your help would be very appreciated. Thank You.

#### login.java

```
public class login extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final Button bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        final Button bRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registernowbutton);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent registerIntent = new 
    Intent(login.this,RegisterUser.class);
                login.this.startActivity(registerIntent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### RegisterUser.java

```
public class RegisterUser extends Activity {
    EditText USER_NAME, USER_PASS, CON_PASS;
    String user_name, user_pass, con_pass;
    Button REG;
    Context ctx = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);
        USER_NAME = findViewById(R.id.reg_user);
        USER_PASS = findViewById(R.id.reg_pass);
        CON_PASS = findViewById(R.id.con_pass);
        REG = findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);
        REG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                user_name = USER_NAME.getText().toString();
                user_pass = USER_PASS.getText().toString();
                con_pass = CON_PASS.getText().toString();

                if(!(user_pass.equals(con_pass))){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Passwords Do Not 
    Match",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    USER_NAME.setText("");
                    USER_PASS.setText("");
                    CON_PASS.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
                    DB.putInformation(DB, user_name, user_pass);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration Success", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();

                }
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

#### DatabaseOperations.java

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int database_version = 1;
    public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE 
    "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+" 
    TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD+" TEXT );";

    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, 
    database_version);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Database created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
        sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database operations","Table created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String 
    pass){
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD, pass);
        SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null,cv);
        Log.d("Database operations", "One raw inserted");
    }
}
```

#### login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context=".login"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="PSU Email"
    android:inputType="text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:background="#ff77aa"
    android:text="Login"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.692" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pennstateshield"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.249" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Not Registered? Please Join!"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registernowbutton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:background="#ff77aa"
    android:text="Register Now"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.692" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

#### activity_register_user.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context="m.rami.psucalculator.RegisterUser"
android:id="@+id/relativeactivityregister">


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/registerpsulogo"
android:layout_width="400dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
android:src="@drawable/pennstateshield"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.249" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/reg_user"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter PSU Email"
    android:inputType="text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/reg_pass"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/reg_user"
    android:layout_below="@+id/reg_user"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/con_pass"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/reg_pass"
    android:layout_below="@+id/reg_pass"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Re-Enter Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.008" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registerbutton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/con_pass"
    android:layout_below="@+id/con_pass"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="#ff77aa"
    android:text="Register"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.692" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Information from Logcat of Errors:

```
04-20 12:37:32.428 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Not late-     
enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-20 12:37:32.437 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator W/zygote: Unexpected 
CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
04-20 12:37:32.841 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator I/InstantRun: starting 
instant run server: is main process
04-20 12:37:33.301 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI 
GL Pipeline
04-20 12:37:33.351 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator I/OpenGLRenderer: 
Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-20 12:37:33.351 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap 
behavior 1
04-20 12:37:33.352 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator W/OpenGLRenderer: 
Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying 
without...
04-20 12:37:33.352 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap 
behavior 0
04-20 12:37:33.428 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglCreateContext: 0xa0e052a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
04-20 12:37:33.488 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:33.608 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:36.566 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:36.745 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator I/AssistStructure: 
Flattened final assist data: 2212 bytes, containing 1 windows, 7 views
04-20 12:37:42.827 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Do partial 
code cache collection, code=23KB, data=27KB
04-20 12:37:42.829 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: After code 
cache collection, code=23KB, data=27KB
04-20 12:37:42.829 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Increasing 
code cache capacity to 128KB
04-20 12:37:42.902 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Do partial 
code cache collection, code=30KB, data=56KB
04-20 12:37:42.902 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: After code 
cache collection, code=30KB, data=56KB
04-20 12:37:42.902 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Increasing 
code cache capacity to 256KB
04-20 12:37:42.902 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: JIT allocated 
71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init> 
(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
04-20 12:37:42.902 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Compiler 
allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init> 
(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
04-20 12:37:42.989 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:43.025 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:43.038 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:43.077 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator I/AssistStructure: 
Flattened final assist data: 2060 bytes, containing 1 windows, 6 views
04-20 12:37:45.457 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Do full code 
cache collection, code=124KB, data=78KB
04-20 12:37:45.460 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: After code 
cache collection, code=122KB, data=53KB
04-20 12:37:47.316 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Do partial 
code cache collection, code=124KB, data=58KB
04-20 12:37:47.320 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: After code 
cache collection, code=124KB, data=58KB
04-20 12:37:47.320 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Increasing 
code cache capacity to 512KB
04-20 12:37:51.958 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator D/Database operations: 
Database created
04-20 12:37:51.962 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator E/SQLiteLog: (1) table 
reg_info has no column named user_password
04-20 12:37:51.965 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator E/SQLiteDatabase: Error 
inserting user_password=Rami user_name=ram6077
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table reg_info has no column named 
user_password (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 
reg_info(user_password,user_name) VALUES (?,?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native 
Method)
at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.
acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.
prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase. 
insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.
insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
at 
m.rami.psucalculator.DatabaseOperations.
putInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:44)
at m.rami.psucalculator.RegisterUser$1.onClick(RegisterUser.java:43)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
04-20 12:37:51.965 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator D/Database operations: 
One raw inserted
04-20 12:37:52.083 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:52.103 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:52.238 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:52.274 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator I/chatty: 
uid=10085(u0_a85) RenderThread identical 1 line
04-20 12:37:52.301 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:52.346 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:52.380 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:37:52.387 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/OpenGLRenderer: 
endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8e9f3500 (Button) with handle 0xa0e03740
04-20 12:37:52.808 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:39:33.362 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Do full code 
cache collection, code=249KB, data=150KB
04-20 12:39:33.363 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: After code 
cache collection, code=245KB, data=134KB
04-20 12:39:44.912 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Do partial 
code cache collection, code=245KB, data=137KB
04-20 12:39:44.913 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: After code 
cache collection, code=245KB, data=137KB
04-20 12:39:44.913 22018-22023/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Increasing 
code cache capacity to 1024KB
04-20 12:40:02.461 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:02.507 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:02.516 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:02.564 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator I/AssistStructure: 
Flattened final assist data: 2060 bytes, containing 1 windows, 6 views
04-20 12:40:16.580 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator D/Database operations: 
Database created
04-20 12:40:16.585 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator E/SQLiteLog: (1) table 
reg_info has no column named user_password
04-20 12:40:16.587 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator E/SQLiteDatabase: Error 
inserting user_password=Rami user_name=ram6077
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table reg_info has no column named 
user_password (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 
reg_info(user_password,user_name) VALUES (?,?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native 
Method)
at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.
acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.
insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.
insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
at 
m.rami.psucalculator.DatabaseOperations.
putInformation(DatabaseOperations.java:44)
at m.rami.psucalculator.RegisterUser$1.onClick(RegisterUser.java:43)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
04-20 12:40:16.588 22018-22018/m.rami.psucalculator D/Database operations: 
One raw inserted
04-20 12:40:16.648 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:16.662 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:16.733 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:16.774 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:16.879 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:16.920 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator I/chatty: 
uid=10085(u0_a85) RenderThread identical 1 line
04-20 12:40:17.056 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 12:40:17.067 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/OpenGLRenderer: 
endAllActiveAnimators on 0x9c5dc880 (Button) with handle 0xa0e03fa0
04-20 12:40:17.361 22018-22048/m.rami.psucalculator D/EGL_emulation: 
eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e032e0)
04-20 18:32:41.232 22018-22024/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: 
Thread[3,tid=22024,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,
Thread*=0xaa3dac00,peer=0x131c0088,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
04-20 18:32:41.375 22018-22024/m.rami.psucalculator I/zygote: Wrote stack 
traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: I forgot to add one more relevant class:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert into table **reg_info** isn't working because of

> **`no column named user_password`**

, as per :-

> ```
> table reg_info has no column named user_password (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO reg_info(user_password,user_name) VALUES (?,?)
> ```

This is likely due to the table having been modified in your table create SQL (user_password column added at a guess), but that hasn't been applied due to how the **`onCreate`** method is invoked.

That is the **`onCreate`** method is invoked **once when the database itself is created** (unless invoked elsewhere), it is not run every time the App is run.

**The quickest fix is to either** :-

1. Delete the App's data from settings/Apps **or**
2. Uninstall the App

and to then rerun the App.

- Noting that this deletes the database and thus any data stored in the database.
- If you need to preserve data then you would need to run the SQL `ALTER TABLE reg_info ADD COLUMN user_password TEXT` at an appropriate place within the code.